# Why do these golang JSON Unmarshal examples behave differently?

Tags: json, go

I'm puzzled by the following behavior and I'm trying to figure out what to do about it.  Can anyone please explain to me why these behave differently?  Why isn't `web_url` read into `Bar.Url`?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type Foo struct {
    Web_url string
}

type Bar struct {
    Url string `json:'web_url'`
}

func TestJson(t *testing.T) {
    j := []byte(`{"web_url":"xyz"}`)

    f := &Foo{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, f)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v, f: %+v\n", err, f)


    b := &Bar{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(j, b)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v, b: %+v\n", err, b)
}
```

Results...

```
go test -v -run TestJson
=== RUN   TestJson
err: <nil>, f: &{Web_url:xyz}
err: <nil>, b: &{Url:}
--- PASS: TestJson (0.00s)
PASS
ok      gitlabsr.nuq.ion.nokia.net/sr/linux/gitlab-tools/internal/junk
```

Comment: The syntax for struct tags uses double quotes. Run `go vet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using single quotes in struct tag definition caused this error.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type Foo struct {
    Web_url string
}

type Bar struct {
    Url string `json:"web_url"`
}

func TestJson(t *testing.T) {
    j := []byte(`{"web_url":"xyz"}`)

    f := &Foo{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, f)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v, f: %+v\n", err, f)


    b := &Bar{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(j, b)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v, b: %+v\n", err, b)
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  The example I was copying using single quotes.

Thank you!